# Building hadoop on Windows Win32 vs amd64

Tags: windows, hadoop, cpu-architecture

I try to build hadoop 2.5.0 on windows to use it in IDEA. But if i startup a VisualStudio Console and use

```
setenv /x64
set TARGET_CPU=x64
```

I get this error message:

```
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.2:exec (compile-ms-winutils) @ hadoop-common ---
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
Build started 27.11.2014 14:11:31.
Project "C:\Users\user\hadoop\hadoop-common\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\winutils.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
  Building solution configuration "Release|Win32".
Project "C:\Users\user\hadoop\hadoop-common\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\winutils.sln" (1) is building "C:\Users\bachmann.s\R
CV\hadoop\hadoop-common\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\winutils.vcxproj.metaproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
Project "C:\Users\user\hadoop\hadoop-common\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\winutils.vcxproj.metaproj" (2) is building "C:\Users
\user\hadoop\hadoop-common\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\libwinutils.vcxproj" (3) on node 1 (default targets).
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\Win32\PlatformToolsets\Windows7.1SDK\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.Windows7.1SDK.targets(20,5): error : You ar
e attempting to build a Win32 application from an x64 environment. If using the Windows 7.1 SDK build environment, type setenv /x86 [C:\Users\user\had
oop\hadoop-common\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\libwinutils.vcxproj]
Done Building Project "C:\Users\user\hadoop\hadoop-common\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\libwinutils.vcxproj" (default targets)
 -- FAILED.
Done Building Project "C:\Users\user\hadoop\hadoop-common\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\winutils.vcxproj.metaproj" (default ta
rgets) -- FAILED.
Done Building Project "C:\Users\user\hadoop\hadoop-common\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\winutils.sln" (default targets) -- FAI
LED.

Build FAILED.

"C:\Users\user\hadoop\hadoop-common\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\winutils.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\user\hadoop\hadoop-common\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\winutils.vcxproj.metaproj" (default target) (2) ->
"C:\Users\user\hadoop\hadoop-common\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\libwinutils.vcxproj" (default target) (3) ->
(_WindowsSDKPrepareForBuild target) ->
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\Win32\PlatformToolsets\Windows7.1SDK\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.Windows7.1SDK.targets(20,5): error : You
are attempting to build a Win32 application from an x64 environment. If using the Windows 7.1 SDK build environment, type setenv /x86 [C:\Users\user\h
adoop\hadoop-common\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\libwinutils.vcxproj]
```

basically saying me to switch to a 32bit Build Enviroment. 
But when i do now

```
setenv /x86
set TARGET_CPU=x86
```

and start a new build, maven gives me the following error:

```
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.2:exec (compile-ms-native-dll) @ hadoop-common ---
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
Build started 27.11.2014 14:17:06.
Project "C:\Users\user\hadoop\hadoop-common\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\native\native.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
  Building solution configuration "Release|Mixed Platforms".
Project "C:\Users\user\hadoop\hadoop-common\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\native\native.sln" (1) is building "C:\Users\user\h
adoop\hadoop-common\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\native\native.vcxproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\x64\PlatformToolsets\Windows7.1SDK\Microsoft.Cpp.x64.Windows7.1SDK.targets(20,5): error : You are at
tempting to build an AMD64 application from an x86 environment. If using the Windows 7.1 SDK, type setenv /x64 [C:\Users\user\hadoop\hadoop-common\had
oop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\native\native.vcxproj]
Done Building Project "C:\Users\user\hadoop\hadoop-common\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\native\native.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAI
LED.
Done Building Project "C:\Users\user\hadoop\hadoop-common\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\native\native.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.


Build FAILED.
```

Why are all the Projects in different Architectures or do i need to set some other options to completly build in one architecture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also have to set the platform correctly.

The complete commands to set the build environment to x64 are:

```
setenv /x64
set TARGET_CPU=x64
set platform=x64
```